# Small black outline around image OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I have this image: [sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgm8y.png)

I'm loading a texture (.png file) into my viewport I'm using

```
// enable blending
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

to get rid of the black alpha channel, however the problem is that there is still a small black line around the sprite, i'm not sure if it's visible in the image or not.
Here's the code I use for my textures:

```
// generate and bind the texture
unsigned int texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

// configure the texture
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

// flip the image vertically so texture isn't upside down
stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);

// load an image while getting the width, height, and number of color channels
int width, height, nrChannels;
unsigned char* data = stbi_load(imageFile, &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);

// if we have the image
if (data)
{
    // create texture and mipmap for the texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
else // we don't have the image
{
    // print
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}
// free the image data and delete it
stbi_image_free(data);
```

Comment: I couldn't see any black line in your sample image. Nevertheless, I know the effect (from my own fiddling) and where it can come from. To fix this, you need a bitmap editor (e.g. GIMP). The reason is (could be) that the pixel color of transparent regions is black. Thus, if texels are merged on the border of opaque regions, the alpha values are mixed as well as the color values. Hence, black and red are mixed which results in ugly looking outline effects. The solution is  simple: fill the color channels with red so that color regions and transparency regions overlap.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I downloaded the image of your link. The anti-aliasing at the border of the red circle looks OK. There is an alpha channel in your image but it contains opaque values only. This is probably not the image you load for your texture, is it?

Comment: FYI: [Black outline in Sprites using transparent PNGs as Textures](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1625)

Comment: While googling, I found another possible reason: The draw order could be wrong so that semi-transparent pixels are drawn in foreground before other pixels in the background. Due to setting the depth value with those pixels, pixels in the background are not drawn anymore resulting in strangle looking cut-out effects. A simple solution is to render (semi-)transparent faces last, a more comprehensive [Order Independent Transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-independent_transparency).

Comment: FYI: [Transparent textures in 3D have an outline](https://community.monogame.net/t/solved-transparent-textures-in-3d-have-an-outline/9008)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Scheff's Cat, for your help. I guess it was just the way it's supposed to appear, it does look like it has a black line and I put it into some other programs and it did the same thing. It's just how it is supposed to appear most sprites that have more detail shouldn't appear that way.